# Wordpress Admin and End user website

Tags: wordpress, admin, end-user

Am new to word-press, i need to build a website like i have an administrator and normal users. Both admin and normal users have a registration form. Admin will decide the fields to be included in normal user's registration form (admin can select the fields from a drop down menu).

Administrator could manage all the normal users (delete,block,approve etc..).For example, normal users are restaurant owners.The owners will register in the website, admin can approve the requests, etc. When i open the website , the website should display all the coffee shops in a map.

How can i do this application in word-press any reference please?

Please help

Thanks

Comment: There are many plugins which could do the job for you. for example: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend/ just look for a front-end panel in the wordpress plugins library and i'm sure you will find something very close if not exactly what you are looking for to accomplish

Comment: This question is better suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Anyways this project is possible in wordpress right?